# Was Lex Luthor intercepting Keefe's payments?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

From [fandom.com](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Wallace_Keefe):

> Lex Luthor interfered all of Keefe's severance payments and returned them to Wayne Enterprises with hate words written in red.

Where in the Ultimate Edition is that shown/explained?

There's the scene with one of Bruce's employees giving him the returned cheques, but nothing to suggest it was Luthor. All the times I've watched it I thought it was Keefe returning the payments.

Comment: I'd appreciate to know what's wrong so I don't do it again.

Comment: I'd like to know as well. It's a perfectly valid question and I thought so too.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is a case of the tail wagging the dog. Once bad info is on the wiki, people have a tendency to repeat it as if it's gospel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that there's no good evidence that Luthor was intercepting Keefe's cheques and good evidence that Keefe was returning them himself.

In addition to the fact that Keefe would have been well aware of the Wayne Fund and there's really no good way that Luthor could have kept that information from him or explained why his cheques weren't coming through, most critically [Keefe has an anti-shrine to Superman in his basement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrlPoDH2sWw&feature=youtu.be&t=8) and regularly boxes off Superman's name in the ***same blood-red marker*** that's used to scrawl hate messages onto the cheques that he gets from the Wayne Fund.

[image]

[image]

That being said, Luthor does refer to ...

> "Little red notes, big bang. You let your family die"

... in his [conversation with Superman](https://youtu.be/MZnFXqhCWIk?t=81), so it's reasonable to assume that he was responsible for the *[final note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfYFC.jpg)* that Batman/Bruce received.

[image]

---

You might also want to note that the final letter is atypical of the others. All of the previous notes were written directly onto cheques. All were written with some variant of *Bruce*, *Wayne* or *B.* at the start of each sentence and the handwriting in the final note is subtly different from the cheques.

> BRUCE WAYNE OPEN YOUR EYES, B. WAYNE I AM YOUR GHOST, BRUCE NO TRUCE,
>   B. WAYNE I HAUNT YOU, BRUCE WAYNE = BLIND

vs.

> YOU LET YOUR FAMILY DIE.

Comment: I'm no graphologist, but you can clearly see that the letter E on the cheques is written with a single downstroke that curves into the lower arm (with the middle and upper arms added afterwards) whereas the letter E on the note is written with a single dowstroke with all three arms added on next. The same inconsistency is found in the letter Y.